# Are volumes mounted to kubernetes pods by PersistentVolumeClaims different for replicas?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a PersistenceVolumeClaim defined by

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: "standard"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

And the containers section of the deployment yaml looks like this

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: abc/xyz:1.2.3
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/store
      name: mystore
  volumes:
  - name: mystore
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-pvc
```

I have a few questions about this set up.

1. Do each replica of my pod get 1GB storage space (Assuming the PersistentVolume has enough space)?
2. How would this behave if the pod replicas are on different kubernetes nodes?

**Edit**

I would like all replicas of my pod to have it's own storage (not a shared one). Is there a way to achieve this without creating a RWM volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do each replica of my pod get 1GB storage space (Assuming the PersistentVolume has enough space)?

No. Since you use one `PersistentVolumeClaim`, you will get one `PersistentVolume`.

> How would this behave if the pod replicas are on different kubernetes nodes?

It will not work, unless you use a volume type that can be used from multiple nodes at once, with [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) `ReadWriteMany` or `ReadOnlyMany`. But you have declared `ReadWriteOnce` in your PersistentVolumeClaim, so it will likely not work.

> I would like all replicas of my pod to have it's own storage (not a shared one). Is there a way to achieve this without creating a RWM volume?

Yes, you can use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) instead of `Deployment`, and use the `volumeClaimTemplates:`-field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited my question with a follow up. Could you please give your suggestion?